# Clearing sharedViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, koin

I am using Koin for injecting viewModel into fragment. My app is single activity. I need that sharedViewModel only in servisFragment and partFragment.
I would like to clear that viewModel from Activity after navigation marked with red.

How can I do that?

[image: navigation]

Code for injecting viewModel

```
    private val servisViewModel by sharedViewModel<ServisViewModel>()
```

Koin sharedViewModel

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.sharedViewModel(
    name: String? = null,
    noinline from: ViewModelStoreOwnerDefinition = { activity as 
    ViewModelStoreOwner },
    noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
) = lazy { getSharedViewModel<T>(name, from, parameters) }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In the traditional nested fragment, we can use `by sharedViewModel(from = { parentFragment as ViewModelStoreOwner})` to bind ViewModel lifecycle to parent fragment lifecycle. But in the navigation component, I have not idea how to get the parent fragment instance.

Comment: I managed to bind with Koin and code above but I don't know how to clear/unboud it and if thats is even needed.

Comment: You don't need to clear just like `by viewModel()` can auto clear when the fragment destory.

Comment: Added code for sharedViewModel. Does it get cleared when fragment is destroyed even if it's using activity as ViewModelStoreOwner like in code above?

Comment: Do you use the navigation component? If true, you can not get the parent fragment by calling `getParentFragment()`. It always returns `NavHostFragment` not your `servisFragment`.

Comment: Yes I am using it. Why do I need parent fragment? As I said I have single Activity Application and all fragments inside that Activity.

Comment: `I need that sharedViewModel only in servisFragment and partFragment`. In your graph, `partFragment` is the child fragment and `servisFragment` is the parent fragment. So, if we can bind `sharedViewModel` to parent fragment, `sharedViewModel` will be clear when you navigate the red path.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/183 and its reply

Comment: When I use `findNavController().navigate(ServisFragmentDirections.Action_servisFragment_to_menuFragment())` to get back to `menuFragment` and then go again to `servisFragment` everything is still in it (Data not cleared).

Comment: Check your parent fragment in `partFragment`. If you bind the wrong parent, the ViewModel will not be clear

Comment: As you said before `getParentFragment()` returns `NavHostFragment`. Is there any way to get `servisFragment`?

Answer (score 4):

if you need to clear all `viewModels` from that `Fragment` try this in your `Fragment`

```
viewModelStore.clear()
```

if you need to clear concrete `ViewModel`  try this

```
getViewModelStore(ViewModelParameters(...)).clear()
```

Comment: getViewModelStore does not accept parameters?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using koin to inject, in the `onDestoy` of the fragment you should use

```
requireActivity().viewModelStore.clear()
```

because viewModelStore directly from fragment will return none to clear

But the problem with this is that it will clear **ALL** the view model scoped within this ViewModelStore. So you won't have control of which ViewModel to clear.